# MotionLayout / NestedScrollView weird scrolling

Tags: android, android-nestedscrollview, android-motionlayout

I'm struggling with motion layout to simulate a CollapsingToolbarLayout

I wanna get something very similar to the  [official examples](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/examples#coordinatorlayout_12)

I follow the code given in the example, but notice a weird scrolling effect when I do the following: scroll slightly from the header towards the top (where the image is).
This triggers the animations, so far so good.

But if I start scrolling counterwise (towards bottom) in the NestedScrollView (below the image) while the fling effect from the previous scroll is still running, it seems like each part are 'stealing' the scroll which produce a weird effect. As soon as the fling from the first scroll stops, the second scroll abruptly resumes and expands fully the collapsible toolbar.

If anyone has an idea to fix this, I will take it!

Showing what happens here:
[image: Motion]

Comment: I finally solved the problem by using nested MotionLayouts (actually, there is an example in [google's demo repo](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/master/ConstraintLayoutExamples/motionlayout/src/main/res/layout/motion_17_coordination.xml)), but i cant tell how to fix this without using two MotionLayouts